# Get records where multiple rows are equal value sql server

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, plsql

I have SQL schema like below:

```
ANo   | Code  |Type  | Date1  | EX_Date|Rd_Date |CPS | Tax 
______|_______| _____|______  |_ ______|_______ |____|__________
B1    |   AM  |  T   |4/1/2014|3/2/2012|4/2/2010| 99 | 1
B1    |   AM  |  T   |5/2/2014|3/5/2012|4/2/2010| 99 | 1
p1    |   4   |  X   |5/8/2014|3/4/2012|5/9/2015| 22 | 2
p2    |   3   |  Y   |8/1/2015|5/6/2011|7/8/2010| 20 | 3
```

Here I want to get records where multiple rows are equal values.The condition is ANo,Code,Type,CPS,Tax needs to be directly compared. And, if Ex_Date and Rd_Date are equal or 10days of each other then it will be considered as duplicate.Note: I wanted to ignore the Date1 column.

So, this above schema should come like:

```
ANo   | Code  |Type  | Date1  | EX_Date|Rd_Date |CPS | Tax 
______|_______| _____|______  |_ ______|_______ |____|__________
B1    |   AM  |  T   |4/1/2014|3/2/2012|4/2/2010| 99 | 1
B1    |   AM  |  T   |5/2/2014|3/5/2012|4/2/2010| 99 | 1
```

Its would be great, if any one can please help me with PLSQL.Sql server is also OK.

Comment: And. You want query to show duplicates?

Comment: Both answers working fine in Oracle, however, its not in SQL server 2008. Any sample modification I need to do for these date field compare?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show duplicates it will be something like

```
select t1.* from Test t1
join Test t2 on 1=1
and t2.ANo = t1.ANo
and t2.Code = t1.Code
and t2."Type" = t1."Type"
and t2.CPS = t1.CPS
and t2.Tax = t1.Tax
and abs(t1.EX_Date - t2.EX_Date)  <= 10
and abs(t1.Rd_Date - t2.Rd_Date)  <= 10
group by t1.ANo, t1.Code,t1."Type", t1.Date1, t1.EX_Date,t1.Rd_Date,t1.CPS, t1.Tax
having count(t1.*) > 1;
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4350c/4)

Comment: This will match every row (and duplicate those rows which have actual matches to other rows).

Comment: @Dmitry - Nice to see this : http://sqlfiddle.com/ . I was unknown to this. Can I make multiple schema here and join different tables as per my requirement. If yes,how? I do not have write access to production, so I wanted to try something here.

Comment: In sqlfinder idk, but in db, if user have grants for both schemes then yes.

Comment: Same way "abs" is not working in SQL Server. How can I do same thing in SQL server 2008. I tried datediff function, but, its not working.Any help?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/584aa/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test ( ANo, Code,"Type", Date1, EX_Date,Rd_Date,CPS, Tax ) AS
          SELECT 'B1', 'AM', 'T', TO_DATE( '2014-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), TO_DATE( '2012-03-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), TO_DATE( '2010-04-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), 99, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'B1', 'AM', 'T', TO_DATE( '2014-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), TO_DATE( '2012-03-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), TO_DATE( '2010-04-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), 99, 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p1', '4',  'X', TO_DATE( '2014-05-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), TO_DATE( '2012-03-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), TO_DATE( '2015-05-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), 22, 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'p2', '3',  'Y', TO_DATE( '2015-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), TO_DATE( '2011-05-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), TO_DATE( '2010-07-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), 20, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TEST t
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 'X'
         FROM   TEST x
         WHERE  x.ROWID  <> t.ROWID
         AND    x.ANo    = t.Ano
         AND    x.Code   = t.Code
         AND    x."Type" = t."Type"
         AND    x.cps    = t.cps
         AND    x.tax    = t.tax
         AND    x.EX_DATE BETWEEN t.EX_DATE - INTERVAL '10' DAY AND t.EX_DATE + INTERVAL '10' DAY
         AND    x.RD_DATE BETWEEN t.RD_DATE - INTERVAL '10' DAY AND t.RD_DATE + INTERVAL '10' DAY
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/584aa/7/0)**:

```
| ANO | CODE | Type |                   DATE1 |                 EX_DATE |                 RD_DATE | CPS | TAX |
|-----|------|------|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|-----|-----|
|  B1 |   AM |    T |   May, 02 2014 00:00:00 | March, 05 2012 00:00:00 | April, 02 2010 00:00:00 |  99 |   1 |
|  B1 |   AM |    T | April, 01 2014 00:00:00 | March, 02 2012 00:00:00 | April, 02 2010 00:00:00 |  99 |   1 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it. Please note that ANO,Code,Type,CPS,Tax are coming from one table and Date1,ex_date,rd_date are coming from a different table. Moreover, if I have 4 records with dates 4,5,6 and 16; then 4,5,6 will be considered as duplicate, and 16 will also be considered as duplicate as well, because, when 6 and 16 will be compared then difference will be 10 and as per condition dates less then equals to 10 is duplicate; hence, all dates 4,5,6,16 are duplicate records.